# Javascript Textarea allow only to delete input

Tags: javascript, textarea, user-input

I have a form with a text area element. 
I want limit input size, once user reaches limit he should be able to clear characters until he reaches the allowed size.
Disabling the element once reached max size will not be efficient as user will not be able to clear text either.
Also, I dont want to clear input on my side as it might be annoying to user.

```
var message = document.getElementById("Id"); 
  message.addEventListener("keydown", callback, false);
  function callback(){
    if(message.value.length > 25){
      alert("text longer than allowed");
//      Allow to delete, do not add.    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect which key is pressed inside your textarea and allow `backspace`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> and navigation with keyboard arrows.

You'll also need to disable the `paste` event if the limit has been reached and cut the pasted text to your limit if its length is longer :

```
message.onpaste = function(e) {
    //Cancel paste if limit has been reached
    if (this.value.length > 25) return false;
    else{
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
        //If there's not enough chars left for the whole paste to go through : cut it
        if(pastedData.length + this.value.length > 25){
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          this.value += pastedData.substring(0,25 - this.value.length + 1);
        }
    }
};

message.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    //8 : Backspace / [37-40] : Arrow keys / ctrlKey : Ctrl + *
    if ([8,37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1 && !e.ctrlKey) {
        if (this.value.length > 25) return false;
    }else return true;
};
```

```js
var message = document.getElementById('myText');
message.onpaste = function(e) {
  if (this.value.length > 25) return false;
  else{
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    
    if(pastedData.length + this.value.length > 25){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      this.value += pastedData.substring(0,25 - this.value.length + 1);
    }
  }
};

message.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if ([8, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1 && !e.ctrlKey) {
    if (this.value.length > 25) return false;
  } else return true;
};
```

```html
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

Comment: or use e.preventDefault(). Also you cannot select text with Ctrl+A or use arrow keys when the text is 25  characters long. Maybe check only for keys adding some text to the input.